# PHP Fatal error: Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found

Tags: php, joomla-3.6, fatal-error, logs, mod-articles-category

I am getting this line in the `error_log` of a Joomla! 3.6.5 site every so often:

```
[21-Dec-2016 18:29:41 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found in /path/to/site/templates/theme/html/mod_articles_categories/default_items.php on line 14
```

Here are the contents of `default_items.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_articles_categories
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

foreach ($list as $item) :
?>
    <li <?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] == JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id))) echo ' class="active"';?>> <?php $levelup = $item->level - $startLevel - 1; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id)); ?>">
        <?php echo $item->title;?></a>
        <?php
        if ($params->get('show_description', 0))
        {
            echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->description, $item->getParams(), 'mod_articles_categories.content');
        }
        if ($params->get('show_children', 0) && (($params->get('maxlevel', 0) == 0) || ($params->get('maxlevel') >= ($item->level - $startLevel))) && count($item->getChildren()))
        {
            echo '<ul>';
            $temp = $list;
            $list = $item->getChildren();
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_articles_categories', $params->get('layout', 'default').'_items');
            $list = $temp;
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        ?>
 </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here are the contents of the core `default_items.php` file for comparison:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_articles_categories
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
    <li <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id))) echo ' class="active"';?>> <?php $levelup = $item->level - $startLevel - 1; ?>
        <h<?php echo $params->get('item_heading') + $levelup; ?>>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->id)); ?>">
        <?php echo $item->title;?>
            <?php if ($params->get('numitems')) : ?>
                (<?php echo $item->numitems; ?>)
            <?php endif; ?>
        </a>
        </h><?php echo $params->get('item_heading') + $levelup; ?>>

        <?php if ($params->get('show_description', 0)) : ?>
            <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->description, $item->getParams(), 'mod_articles_categories.content'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($params->get('show_children', 0) && (($params->get('maxlevel', 0) == 0)
            || ($params->get('maxlevel') >= ($item->level - $startLevel)))
            && count($item->getChildren())) : ?>
            <?php echo '<ul>'; ?>
            <?php $temp = $list; ?>
            <?php $list = $item->getChildren(); ?>
            <?php require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_articles_categories', $params->get('layout', 'default') . '_items'); ?>
            <?php $list = $temp; ?>
            <?php echo '</ul>'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**How can I resolve this error?**

---

*Note: These errors only began on Nov 3, so I assume this was related to the **3.6.4** update or a minor update to PHP 5.5.*

Comment: I recently got this error on a site I updated - but I can't recall what I did to fix it not even which site that was. If I manage to recall more on this case, I will post here.

Comment: the answer I posted is the solution to this issue and its a bug fix committed for future releases of joomla. Since many may arrive here [**with the same issues**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/19005/joomla-how-to-trace-error-0-class-contenthelperroute), accept the answer so they can see it is answered and to use the suggestion to resolve their issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this issue again with another site and remembered what the problem is. This module is that it has changed the way it's loading its helper File/Class and the way the `helper.php` file is loading the `ContentHelperRoute` Class, so the `ContentHelperRoute` isn't anymore available at the `default_items.php` template file.

From:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/helper.php';
```

inside the mod_articles_categories.php to include the helper file and Class, and:

```
require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';
```

inside the helper.php, to include the `ContentHelperRoute` file/Class, it now loads the said Classes with `JLoader::register();`

But this way the `ContentHelperRoute` isn't available anymore in the `default_items.php` where it's getting called.

To fix this bug, you can edit the mod_articles_categories.php and add this line after the `defined('_JEXEC') or die;`

```
JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');
```

#### Update

This is a bug as shown here:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/13590

You can apply the above fix to the mod_articles_categories.php and wait for the next Joomla release.

Comment: I have added that line. I will let you know if the error reappears.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that recent versions of Joomla! have replace `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. I have replaced that code on line 14 and will continue to monitor the `error_log` to see if the issue is resolved.

---

**Update:** I have received the same error at least once since this "fix", so it appears it did not solve the issue.