# Debugging methods- How can I determine the source of the error - "0 Class 'ContentHelperRoute'"?

Tags: php, joomla-3.6, debug

My question is **what are some alternative methods of determining or tracing the source of an error in Joomla when the source of error isn't shown by normal debugging means?** By normal debug methods, I mean the ones I have tried.

I am trying to determine the source of the error 0 Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found on some components (mostly Search component and DJ classfieds in Joomla 3.6.5).
I've found that the problem goes away after a page refresh but it appears again very often.

**I tried:**

- enabling debug switch in configuration
- set PHP error level to max
- search error in server log
  but the resulting debug information doesn't allow me to pinpoint what is causing the error.
- I've looked at the pointed solution:
  [PHP Fatal error: Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18698/php-fatal-error-class-contenthelperroute-not-found)
  but it is not the same because in my case as I have no info about the
  source of the error. I understand that there is an error but I cannot
  find where it occurs.

**Are there any other ways to trace errors under Joomla? I appreciate any suggestions.**

**Screen:**
[image]

Comment: Is this the error message you get? Where do you get it? What do you see in the screen? Is it possible that your issue is this one [**PHP Fatal Error Class contentHelperRoute Not Found**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18698/php-fatal-error-class-contenthelperroute-not-found) and the suggested solution the fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18698/php-fatal-error-class-contenthelperroute-not-found)

Comment: @FFrewin - in my case there is no way to determine where problem occurs. Onlu Class not found. There is no additional info in debug panel, no php error, no single line in server log. Problem sometimes occurs sometimes not, it occurs in many components.

Comment: My main question is not how to solve this error but: is there any other way to debug Joomla app?

Comment: It may be that something changes the error_reporting in your configuration / site, e.g. your hosting provider may have disabled error logging

Comment: @FFrewin Error reporting works because there are some notices when I enable error reporting. Just no fatal errors, nothing above notices. Now I'm disabling all addons one by one and checking if this helps.

Comment: @Barto Next time perhaps you could try using a PHP debugging tool such as xdebug.

Comment: Aaah, I edited the question without reading the answers :X

Answer (score 1):

Per [FFrewin](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18849/5638):

> To fix this bug, you can edit the mod_articles_categories.php and add
>   this line after the `defined('_JEXEC') or die;`:
>
> ```
> JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php
> ```

---

Reference: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18849/5638

Answer (score 0):

I found only one solution. I switched off one component/theme/module after another and found that problem was with the code in mod_articles_category override in template. I don't know exactly why but it was not necessary so I removed it:

```
$nadkategoria=$item->displayCategoryTitle;
if ($item->parent_title!='ROOT') $nadkategoria='<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->parent_id)) . '">' . $item->parent_title . '</a>';?>
```

Comment: So as I guessed, your issue was the from the same module as described in the [**PHP Fatal error: Class 'ContentHelperRoute' not found**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18698/php-fatal-error-class-contenthelperroute-not-found)